# Simple formula for spinning bottle

Tags: javascript, physics

I'm working on a small wine lottery web-app for the company. When it comes down to 10 numbers it will place them in a circle and spin a wine bottle; however, I haven't been able to get the animation for the spinning bottle realistic.

The app will pick a number then, consequently, an angle that points towards it. After that it starts spinning around 10 laps then ends up pointing towards the number.
Should I simulate friction or use some sort of curve to do this?

Just to clarify: I'm looking for a formula or something similar to set the bottle's speed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `-webkit-transform`, why not set the `-webkit-transition` property to `ease-out`?

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dosboy/KGhAJ/

Comment: Hey,
That's what I ended up doing. Instead of using ease-out I made my own curve using [Ceaser](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/):

`cubic-bezier(0.185, 1.000, 0.420, 1.000);`

Comment: Never seen Ceaser before. Nice link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to animate via this method at all?

I know a lot of online gambling sites do this, and essentially (assuming the bottle always starts at the same point), you could create a flash file containing the 10 animations, and just feed in via parameters the end result (obfuscate it if you don't want people seeing it).

The user gets a nice flash animation, your random number generator still still be in effect, and you have no need to generate complex animations cutting down implementation time (assuming you can find someone to do the flash animations for you).

Cheers,
Terry

Comment: The problem is not making it spin, it's making it spin realistically.

Comment: absolutely - a flash animation can do this for sure - I can't give you a URL without revealing which gambling site I work for, but we use this technique extensively across games.

if you take out the javascript and phsyics from this, then it becomes an animation task, and flash is great at creating convincing animations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) JS library, specifically [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html).

Comment: I've got the rotating part covered (I just use -webkit-transform), what I'm looking for is a way to make it look just like a spinning bottle in real life.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great example of this here: http://www.bookatable.com/win/

Uses RaphealJS as mentioned above.